# Evaluation of an integral when the exponent is a real number

Tags: integration

Is there any general method for finding the following integral, $$\displaystyle\int\tan^x\theta\ d\theta$$ Where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. For $x\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ we can easily find a recursion. But I can't even find a recursion or any method to evaluate the integral when $x\leq -3$ and $x$ is an integer. Can someone help me with this problem?

---

**Note:-**

If there is any paper that deals with this kind of evaluation problem, a link to the paper will also be appreciated.

Comment: Mathematica returns $$\frac{\tan ^{a+1}(x) \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+1}{2};\frac{a+1}{2}+1;-\tan ^2(x)\right)}{a+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need the method, not only the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't have commented if I was able to solve it.

Comment: @Integrator. Nice modesty ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @Integrator. By the way, do you know if Mathematica is able to generate a recursive formula for expression such as, say,$$ \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+1}{2};\frac{a+3}{2};-y^2\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No!(*I don't know*)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \tan^x\theta d\theta 
$$
let $\tan \theta = v$
$$
\int v^x \frac{1}{1+v^2}dv
$$

$$
I(x) = \int \frac{v^x}{v^2+1}dv = \frac{v^{x-1}}{x-1} - \int \frac{v^{x-2}}{v^2+1}dv  = \frac{v^{x-1}}{x-1} - I(x-2)
$$
maybe this recursive relation will help..
$$
I(x) + I(x-2) = \frac{\tan^{x-1}\theta}{x-1}\\
\implies I(x+2) + I(x) = \frac{\tan^{x+1}\theta}{x+1}
$$
or maybe 
$$
I(x-2) = -I(x) +  \frac{\tan^{x-1}\theta}{x-1}
$$
with 
$$
I(-3) = - I(-1) - \frac{\tan^{-2}\theta}{2} = -I(1) +\mathbf{\frac{1}{0}} - \frac{\tan^{-2}\theta}{2}
$$
it seems computing $x = -3$ blows up..but I wait for the peer review process :).

whilst not checking your problem directly..lets see
$$
\int \tan^2 \theta d\theta = \int \sec^2 \theta - 1 d\theta = \tan \theta - \theta
$$
now with the recusive formula
$$
I(2) + I(0) = \tan \theta \implies I(2) = \tan \theta - I(0)
$$
$$
I(0) = \int 1 d\theta = \theta
$$
thus
$$
I(2) = \tan \theta - \theta
$$
up to a constant which I have not included here